# If $T$ is normal and $T^2=-I$, then T is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

From an exercise list:

> Let $V$ be a inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ a normal operator such that $T^2=-I$. Prove that T preserves the inner product, i.e. $\langle Tu,Tv\rangle = \langle u,v \rangle, \forall u,v\in V$.

I found a bunch of equalities. $T^2$, $(T^\ast)^2$ and $TT^\ast$ are unitary. Also, $\langle Tu,Tv\rangle=\langle T^\ast u,T^\ast v\rangle$. But I did not get to the result. I feel like I am missing something about the adjoint operator because I can not get rid of it.

Comment: Did you try the unitary diagonalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consequence of the spectral theorem for normal operators reads as follows:

Let $T$ be normal. Then:

$T$ is unitary $\quad  \iff \quad$ $ \sigma(T) \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}$.

If $T$ is normal, $T^2=-I$ and if $z \in \sigma(T)$, then $z^2 \in \sigma(T^2)$. Hence $z^2=-1$. Therefore

$$ \sigma(T) \subseteq\{i,-i\} \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Let $u \in V$. Then

$||(T^{*}+T)u||^2=(T^{*}u+Tu| T^{*}u+Tu)=....$

Its your turn to show that $||(T^{*}+T)u||=0$.

Since $u$ was arbitrary, we get $T^{*}=-T$, hence

$$T^{*}T=TT^{*}=I.$$

Comment: Why $||(T^{\ast}+T)u||=0$?